# MySQL Ignoring Outliers with Standard Deviations

Tags: mysql, sql, outliers

I need to build a query that can calculate the averages and count whilst ignoring outliers from standard deviations.

I have two tables in Mysql (P and A) with these attributes:

P = Payments:

```
Value_gbp
Paymentid
Account 
rfx_ref
```

A = Accounts:

```
Accountid
Entity_type
Settlment_model
rfx_ref
```

So far i have got this:

```
SELECT 
Account, 
COUNT(value_GBP) AS '# Of Payments', 
TRUNCATE(AVG(value_GBP),2) As 'Avg Value'
FROM payments, 

LEFT JOIN( 
SELECT STDDEV(value_gbp) as std_gbp
FROM payments, accounts 
WHERE payments.paymentid = accounts.acountid
AND Entity_type = 'company'
AND settlement_model = 'payment agent'
GROUP BY account
) outlier 

On payments.paymentid = accounts.acountid
WHERE payments.value_gbp<=outlier.std_gbp*2
AND Entity_type = 'company'
AND settlement_model = 'payment agent'
GROUP BY account
```

But it is falling down on the line that states:

```
On payments.paymentid = accounts.acountid
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can't have a comma before `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: The main query can't access tables in the subquery.

Comment: In furure it is better to show us the actual error message rather than guess where your error is

Comment: Your top-level `JOIN` is not aware of `accounts` DB.  You need to `JOIN` with `outlier` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs to select `accounts.accountid`, and then you need to use this in the `JOIN` condition.

I also think your definition of an outlier is wrong. It shouldn't be more than 2 standard deviations, it should be something that's more than 2 standard deviations from the average. So the subquery needs to return both the average and standard deviation, then you compare the distances.

```
SELECT 
    account, 
    COUNT(value_GBP) AS '# Of Payments', 
    TRUNCATE(AVG(value_GBP),2) As 'Avg Value'
FROM payments 
JOIN( 
    SELECT accountid, AVG(value_gpb) AS avg_gbp, STDDEV(value_gbp) as std_gbp
    FROM payments, accounts 
    WHERE payments.paymentid = accounts.acountid
    AND Entity_type = 'company'
    AND settlement_model = 'payment agent'
    GROUP BY accountid
) outlier 
On payments.paymentid = outlier.accountid
JOIN accounts ON payments.paymentid = accounts.accountid
WHERE ABS(payments.value_gbp - outlier.avg_gpb) <= outlier.std_gbp*2
AND Entity_type = 'company'
AND settlement_model = 'payment agent'
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Hi, 

This query doesnt work.. 

It falls down on the last WHERE clause - SQL wont recognise 'entity_type' or 'settlement model'. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Right, it needs to join with `accounts` again to get that.